# How can i also get the numbers

Tags: c#

I would like to get the value after a specific line, I tried with `if()` (fail badly) So I wondered if there are any command that can get the value, after given line? In this case (sub1:...) or use the given line to find the whole line from List?

```
   private void btnTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Test1 = "@sub1:1001 \t @sub2:1002";
        getValue(Test1);
    }

    public void getValue(string tekst)
    {
        char[] trim = { '@','\t' };
        myList = tekst.Split(' ').ToList();
        foreach (string c in myList)
        {
           string d = c.Trim(trim);

            if (d == "sub1")
            {
                txtT1.Text = d;
            }
            if (d == "sub2")
            {
                txtT2.Text = d;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: What is the expected result? Having `1001` and `1002` in the `Text` members of the objects `txtT1` and `txtT2`?

Comment: what i expected result are = sub:1001. into a textbox name txtT1.
and sub:1002 intro textbox txtT2.
@Codor

Comment: Just split it at the colon after you split it at the spaces and grab the `[1]` array and that should be your number.

Comment: Use `d.StartsWith("sub1")` and `d.StartsWith("sub2")`

Comment: that work just as i wanted :D ty very much @ArturoMenchaca

Comment: Try following :             var results = tekst.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select((x, i) => new { item = x, index = i }).ToList();

Comment: Are you trying to get the numbers only or the whole string after `@ \t`.

Answer (score 0):

Using StartsWith as was mentioned should work. The code would look like this:

```
public void getValue(string tekst)
    {
        char[] trim = { '@', '\t' };
        IList<string> myList = tekst.Split(' ').ToList();
        foreach (string c in myList)
        {
            string d = c.Trim(trim);

            if (d.StartsWith("sub1"))
            {
                txtT1.Text = d;
            }
            if (d.StartsWith("sub2"))
            {
                txtT2.Text = d;
            }
        }
    }
```